# ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead - occured while using model.predict()

Tags: python, arrays

I'm struggling a bit with `LinearRegression` from `Sk.Learn`

Based on a excel sheet with costs of the last 20 year, I'm trying to use linear regression for estimating costs (just as an example), as you can see in the following code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_excel("C:/.../.../.../costs.xlsx")

x = df.loc[:,'year']
y = df.loc[:,'costs']

xsl = []

for xi in x:
    xsl.append([xi])

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(xsl,y)
model.predict([2020])
```

The problem starts with the `model.predict` function.

Once I try to start my code, I always get the following message:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013
 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020].
```

According to the information I have found on the internet, I have to reshape the  data. But I still don't know exactly how.

Is there anybody who has a clue how to do it?

Comment: `model.predict([[2020]])`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

`array=[2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020]`

with

`array=[[2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020]]`.

and for prediction use 2D array as well: `[[2020]]`

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because of your last line, where you provided a 1D array `[2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020]`

Try changing it to `array = [[2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020]]`, with an array nested in the other, creating a 2D array.